# parent pom cannot find executable

Tags: java, maven, ant

In one of my child pom I have the following ant task:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>generate-sources</id>
                     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                     <configuration>
                       <tasks>
                          <mkdir dir="target/generated-sources"/>
                          <echo message="${basedir}"/>
                          <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="protoc/protoc.exe">
                             <arg value="--java_out=target/generated-sources"/>
                             <arg value="--proto_path=src/main/protos"/>
                             <arg value="src/main/protos/updateinfo.proto"/>
                        </exec>
                       </tasks>
                       <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
                     </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
             </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I execute the child pom all is well, the protoc can generate all the protobuff java classes.

But if I execute the parent POM the ant task cannot find the protoc.exe. I checked the ${basedir} and they are both the same. The error message contains the path the ant task looked for the executable and the printed path is correct.

```
"protoc\protoc.exe" (in directory "<Correct child project path>")
```

Comment: Seems like a relative path issue from the parent pom. Just to confirm if this is the issue, could you hard code the full path of protoc.exe and give a try ? If it works fine then need to fix the relative path.

Comment: If I prepend  ${basedir}/ -> ${basedir}/protoc/protoc.exe it works.

Comment: Cool ..so its a missing slash..